# Multiple foreign key columns vs multiple join tables

Tags: mysql, database, join, foreign-keys, database-normalization

This is yet another database normalization question/discussion but i'm hoping to get a some additional perspective on the trade offs, advantages, disadvantage of different scenerios for multiple foreign key columns vs multiple join/intersection tables as I can't seem to find any practical information or advice for how MYSQL would optimize or fail on different approaches.

I'm asking as a general guidance for how others approach for objects with multiple 1:N relationships and foreign keys but a majority of them will always be null.

As a basic example let's say I have a Project Management app with a `uploads` table for storing upload files information. For "scale" theres 20 Million current uploads, with 1000 added daily.

Uploads can have a direct relation to a couple different objects as it's "parent" or "owner". Directly to a Project, directly to a Todo, and directly to a Comment. Each upload would only ever have a single relationship at a time never multiple.

Potential options for structuring I see

**Option 1: Single table multiple foreign key columns**

uploads
`upload_id, filepath, project_id, todo_id, comment_id`

foreign keys for project_id, todo_id, comment_id.

Potential Problem: Large amount of null values in foreign keys. Potentially slow writes/locks in high volumes due to fk constraints and the additional index sizes.

**Option 2: Multiple Intersection/Join tables**

uploads
`upload_id, filepath`

project_uploads
`project_id, upload_id`

todo_uploads
`todo_id, upload_id`

comment_uploads
`comment_id, upload_id`

foreign keys on all columns for *_uploads tables

Potential Problem: People will confuse for N:N instead of 1:N relationship. "Relative", but more difficult selects to produce in application layer, especially when selecting uploads for projects as you would need to join all tables to get the entire list of project Ids for the uploads since todos and comments both would also belong to a parent.

**Option 3: Single Relation/Join table with a type**

uploads
`upload_id, filepath`

objects_uploads
`upload_id, object_id, type`
foreign key on upload_id, standard indexes on object_id and type.

Potential Problem: more confusing schema, not truely "relational" or normalized

I'd also like to throw out the potential of using JSON fields on individual objects and just always enforcing project_id on the uploads. I have very limited experience with JSON field types or their pitfalls. I'm assuming selections to get uploads specifically parented/uploaded to a todo or comment would be far more difficult as you would need to select the ids out of the json.

Are there any other approaches or considerations I'm overlooking? Are their specific consideration to follow based on different workloads, higher write volumes, high read, etc. Thanks for any information, insights or resources.

**Edit**
To clarify, I understand that the above outlines can represent differences in schemes/relationships of the objects. I'm really only thinking about write and select performance and considerations or tradeoffs to make around indexes/constraints and joins.Specifically for this question i'm less concerned about referential integrity or 100% data integrity.

I've modified some language in the my original example above. I'm looking for ideal configurations for objects that can be related to many different objects as but never at the same time leaving most foreign key columns null. Here is a similar questions from 3.5 years ago...
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/335284/disadvantages-of-using-a-nullable-foreign-key-instead-of-creating-an-intersectio

Basically trying to find some general advice when to consider or optimize in the different ways, gauge any real impact of large amount of nulls in Foreign keys and potential reasons for when to prefer different approaches.

Comment: Your "options" realizes 3 different schemes. Only one of them (or maybe none) matches your system.

Comment: I realize those options have different schemes, however I'm not following you when you say they don't match the system. I could most definitely generate the necessary frontend views or select different "lists" of uploads with all three options I outlined. I'm definitely would not ever call myself a DBA so if there's anything I can do to clarify please let me know.

Comment: Imagine a simplified picture - there are 3 related entities, and formally Y and Z are properties of X. 2 different schemes are possible. The first is that Y and Z are properties of X directly, for example, this is the relationship between a theater ticket, a row of seats, and a seat number. The second - Y and Z form an intermediate virtual entity-the relationship T, which is an attribute of X, for example, this is the relationship between a person booked ticket to a theater show, a show (with datetime), and a ticket (with row and seat). Formalized descriptions looks similar but differs.

Comment: As I mentioned above and below. I realize in traditional data modeling sense these are different schemes and that traditionally what I outlined in option 2 would be a many to many vs the many to one relationships in option 1.

Comment: No traditions. There exists real system, with its internal relations and dependencies, and there exists one adequate database model of it which matches completely, and a lot of models which looks like they're matched but they either matched partially or not matched at all.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 models three many-to-one relationships. That is, a given upload can have at most one reference to project, at most one reference to todo, and at most one reference to comment. This would be a simple way to model these as many-to-one relationships. Don't shy away from using NULLs, they don't take storage space.

Option 2 models three many-to-many relationships. A given upload may be associated with multiple projects, multiple todos, and multiple comments. I think this is what Akina was commenting about above. If your application needs these to be many-to-many relationships, then you need these three intersection tables to model that data. If you don't need these to be many-to-many relationships, then don't create these tables.

Option 3 is not a relational data model at all. It conflicts with several normal forms.

Comment: for option 1 is there any consideration/trade offs you would make based on volumes of data. eg 1 specific foreign key being used at far greater volume then the rest? say there was a table with 30 million rows,  20 million reference comment only and the other foreign keys are null. I guess I'm really asking is there performance considerations for NULLS in indexes? I realize that option 2 would traditional be used for many to many relationships, I was generally thinking that forcing selects through vastly reduced table sizes would potentially perform better as it grows.

Comment: I also realize option 3 is not a true "relational" scheme but would work... Is there in any world you would take this approach?

Comment: There is no reason to use option 3. It has no benefits over option 1, it only increases the risk of anomalies.

Comment: MySQL supports NULLs in indexes fine.

Comment: I prob should mention that Option one is how I typically set these types of relationships, I've worked in database that have used all of them. I guess I'm questioning the many articles on the Evils of nulls in foreign keys, and was hoping someone could provide some guidance or considerations around foreign key relationships when there are lots of nulls.

Comment: MySQL has no problem with nulls in indexes. Perhaps other RDBMS implementations have problems in that scenario.